# Can I set a value in the onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a link and on clicking the link I want to set the value of a flag variable to 1. Is that possible? Like

```
<a id='ctr' href='#' onclick='flag=1'> Hello </a>
```

And also how to write the function for the onclick event on the same line, like instead of

```
<a id='ctr' href='#' onclick='call_this();'> Hello </a>
 function call_this(){
     flag=1;
 }
```

can I have the call_this function in the onclick line itself?

**EDIT2**

Now I have the code like this. Inside the onclick event, the value is stored in the $selectedId correctly. But When I try to pass that value in the url, I do not get the correct value. The last value in the for loop is passed.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){

 <?php foreach ($Forms as $r): ?>

     $("<a id='<?php echo $ctr['Form']['id'];?> href='#' onclick='flag=1'> Hello </a>").appendTo("#header").click(function(){
     <?php $selectedId=$r['Form']['id'];?>
     alert("selId: "+<?php echo $selectedId;?>);//here the selected value is echoed
 });
 </script>

 <a href="http://localhost/Example/new/export?height=220&width=350&id=<?php echo $selectedId;?>" class="thickbox button" title= "Export" >Export</a>
```

here the id is passed as 4,which is the last value in the php for loop.

Comment: You really should swap your use of ' and " to allow for correct attribute syntax attributename="attribute-value". Instead of <a id='ctr' you should write <a id="ctr"

Answer (score 8):

Since you have an ID on your anchor element, you can easily find it and bind the event.

If it's a simple action, you can use an anonymous function rather than having to declare a function on the global scope:

```
window.onload = function () {

  // Bind events...

  document.getElementById('ctr').onclick = function () {
    flag1 = 1;
    return false; // stop the browser from following the link
  };

  // ....
};
```

**Edit:** Looking at your edit, the jQuery document.ready event fires when the page load, at this time you flag still have `null` assigned.

Note that you are only adding the anchor element to the DOM, and then you make an if statement.

Since you use jQuery you can use it to bind the [click](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click) event to the newly created element:

```
var flag=null;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('<a id="ctr" href="#"> Hello </a>').appendTo('#header').click(function () {
    flag = 1; 
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the browser from following the link
  });
});
```

You can do this since the [appendTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/appendTo) function returns the newly created DOM element, and you can bind events directly to it.

Comment: six answers and only one that knows what they're talking about. +1

Comment: This will cause a problem, however if executed before 'ctr' is fully loaded. You will need to bind a function to the window.onload event, and execute this code within it.

Comment: I get what I wanted with ur code.. Thanks a lot.. I actually wanted to set a php variable,$selectedId to the id ctr which is also a php variable(id=<?=ctr;?>. The value got saved in the $selectedId variable. But when I try to use it later,to pass it as an element in the url, the last value of the ctr in the for loop is only updated.  i.e if ctr={1,2,3,4} and I select 2, the value passed in the url is 4. Why? Can u help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with little adjustment it should work. But you should know that the best practice for using javascript is have *ALL* your javascript in an external file. This keeps your html "clean", makes editing easier, and gives you a better overview of what's happening.

**contents of the file my.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hello :-)</title>
        <script language="javascript" src="my.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="ctr">Set var value</a><br />
    <a href="#" id="check">Check var value</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Contents of the file my.js:**

```
var flag = 0;

function init()
{
    var ctr_element = document.getElementById('ctr');
    ctr_element.onclick = function()
    {
        flag = 1;
        return false;
    }

    var check_element = document.getElementById('check');
    check_element.onclick = function()
    {
        alert(flag);
        return false;
    }
}

window.onload = init;
```

PS. Even better practice would be the use of a class, so you have less risk of accidentally overwriting your variables. (especially when also using 3rd part libraries etc).
But I recommend you leave that for another day, when your confident enough about your skills.

If you're interested in writing as crossbrowser compatible code, you might want to take a look at libraries like prototype, jquery or dojo. (there are more) They make your js life so much easier :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes.

To test #1, I added an alert like this:

```
<a id='ctr' href='#' onclick='flag=1; alert(flag);'>Hello</a>
```

To test number #2, I added an alert as well:

```
<a id='ctr' href='#' onclick='function call_this() { flag=1; alert(flag); } call_this();'>Hello</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but it's not a good idea.

Scattering code in inline events leads to a convoluted and difficult-to-follow code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set flag in onclick(but this flag should be global)

```
<script>var flag=null;</script>
<a id='ctr' href='#' onclick='flag=1'> Hello </a>
```

and yes you can define function inline.

```
<a id='ctr' href='#' onclick='function call_this(){flag=1;};call_this();'> Hello </a>
```

But i must warn you that this is not right design. Better to have all javascript in js files. And set up only handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can have both JS codes in the elements onclick property, but usually that's an ugly solution and you should avoid it. It's better to place all your JS scripts in a separate  block or a separate file and call it from there.